# Non-static method App\Collaboration::project() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, controller

I need show project collaborators on each project in My laravel app. this is My Collaborator table,

```
id  project_id collaborator_id
 1       1           5
 2       2           8
 3       4           5
```

and I have queryScope in My Collaborator model,

```
 public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }
```

and collaborator method to Get all the collaborators on this project

```
public function getCollaborators($id)
    {
        $collaborators = Collaboration::project($id)->get();
        return $collaborators;
    }
```

and route

```
Route::get('/project/{project}/collaborators', function($id){ 
       $collaborators = \App\Collaboration::project()->get(); // this is line 150
       $project = \App\Project::findOrFail($id);
       return view('collaborators.form',compact('collaborators','project')); 
    })->name('collaborators.form');
```

now when I go to the show project collaboratos following error is coming,

```
ErrorException in routes.php line 150: Non-static method App\Collaboration::project() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

but this route is working and show all collaborators in the collaborator

```
Route::get('/project/{project}/collaborators', function($id){ 
       $collaborators = \App\Collaboration::all();
       $project = \App\Project::findOrFail($id);
       return view('collaborators.form',compact('collaborators','project')); 
    })->name('collaborators.form');
```

but I need show only collaborators on each project who related only to that project. how can fix this problem?

Comment: no any idea here

Comment: need some idea to solve this problem

Comment: i think you should use many to many relationship here. read more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: witch models between should I use many to many relationship?

Comment: `Project` and `Collaboration`

Comment: and i think you get this error because you already have `project` method in your `Collaboration` model except the scope

Comment: I cant understand what you mean can you simply me?